# joining columns of same table with different criteria - SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am able to query with one condition ( as shown in image below ) but when i query with couple of criterias and trying to create two same columns of same table with different criteria, i get no result. 2nd Image is the expected result which i am not able to retrieve. Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
select save_line from save_output_table  
where execution_id in ('292') 
  and seq_id = '0' 
  and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC

+------------+
| Save_line  |
+------------+
|         17 |
|         22 |
|         23 |
+------------+



SELECT 
( select save_line 
  from save_output_table
  where execution_id in ('292') 
    and seq_id = '0' 
    and save_type='R' 
    order by line_id ASC 
) as save_line1,
( select save_line 
  from save_output_table  
  where execution_id in ('286') 
    and seq_id = '0' 
    and save_type='R' 
    order by line_id ASC 
) as save_line2
from save_output_table 

 +-------------+------------+
 | Save_line 1 | Save_line2 |
 +-------------+------------+
 |          17 |          9 |
 |          22 |          5 |
 |          23 |          3 |
 +-------------+------------+
```

Sample Data :

```
 +---------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
 | execution_id  | seq_id | save_type | line_id | save_line |
 +---------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
 |           286 |      0 | R         |       1 |        17 |
 |           286 |      0 | R         |       2 |        22 |
 |           286 |      0 | R         |       3 |        23 |
 |           286 |      0 | D         |       1 |        17 |
 |           286 |      0 | D         |       2 |        22 |
 |           286 |      0 | D         |       3 |        23 |
 |           292 |      0 | R         |       1 |         9 |
 |           292 |      0 | R         |       2 |         5 |
 |           292 |      0 | R         |       3 |         3 |
 |           292 |      0 | D         |       1 |        98 |
 |           292 |      0 | D         |       2 |       622 |
 |           292 |      0 | D         |       3 |       273 |
 +---------------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your expected result need more logic to achieve. Let's say your column x1 have result in 3 rows: a, b, c; your column x2 have 4 rows: x, y, z, t. So what will be your expected result? `(a-x, b-y, c-z, null-t)` or `(a-y,b-t,c-z,null-x)` or `(a-x, a-y, a-z, a-t, b-x, b-y,.........)`

Comment: @PhamX.Bach consider them one row. I just need to select the same column twice with different conditions and my query is not giving me the correct output. its just giving me the first row all the times.

Comment: You description is unclear, and your expected result is just two copies of the same output. Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: @CL. I have editted the example output tables. To make it clear I want the same column result side by side to different conditions. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: This does not show how the rows are joined. Show some sample data, not only the desired results.

Comment: @CL. I have edited the questions with sample table data. I am querying this table and fetching two same rows with different criteria as explained in the question.

Comment: What is the relationship between the values `17` and `9` in the first result line? That they have the same `line_id`?

Comment: @CL. For every execution id and save type its starts from 1 and goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want lists of save_line in order by line_id, in different columns according to save_type and execution_id, you need to pivot. There are a few different ways you can do this. Here are a couple that should work no matter what flavor of SQL you are using:

```
SELECT line_id, 
max(CASE WHEN execution_id = '292' and save_type = 'R' then save_line end) R_292,
max(CASE WHEN execution_id = '286' and save_type = 'R' then save_line end) R_286
FROM save_output_table
GROUP BY line_id
```

or

```
SELECT t1.save_line save_line1,
t2.save_line save_line2
FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM save_output_table
    WHERE save_type = 'R'
    and execution_id = '292'
    ) t1

JOIN (SELECT *
    FROM save_output_table
    WHERE save_type = 'R'
    and execution_id = '286'
    ) t2
ON t1.line_id = t2.line_id
```

Note: for the second option, the join only gives complete lists if there are the same number of line_ids for each condition. If there aren't, you should change it to a FULL OUTER JOIN, which wouldn't work in MySQL and possibly others.